# How to use static code analyzer introduced in android ndk r8e?

Tags: android, android-ndk, analyzer

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

As the above link suggests, android ndk r8e :

> Added static code analyzer for Linux/MacOSX hosts. For information on using the analyzer, see CHANGES.HTML.

In CHANGES.HTML:

> - Added static code analyzer for Linux/MacOSX hosts
>
>   1. For ndk-build, either export NDK_ANALYZE=1 or add it to the command-line.
>   2. For standalone, please refer to ndk-build for example to run scan-build
>        using /path/to/standalone/bin//analyzer.

I added the ndk-build NDK_ANALYZE=1 to build command and it builds fine. But how exactly can I use the analyzer to detect memory problems? I didn' t find any documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following line in "Console" of eclipse when building the NDK project. I think it' s the answer.

> scan-build: Using '/opt/android-ndk/toolchains/llvm-3.2/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/armeabi/analyzer' for static analysis

And in the console at last it shows:

> scan-build: 1 bugs found.
>   scan-build: Run 'scan-view /tmp/scan-build-2013-03-29-4' to examine bug reports.

It detects basic errors such as divide by zero, not memory issues, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure NDK_ANALYZE will help to detect memory leak or not. Currently I'm using Eclipse's plugin cppcheclipse, which can be found [here](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/cppcheclipse/). It has static analysis to check if your code is prone to memory leak.